# 404 Errors in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: updates, wine, update-manager, 13.10

Just installed ubuntu 13.10 
I did apt-update in terminal and sow this

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net /ubuntu/saucy amd64 Packages                       
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net /ubuntu/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net /ubuntu/saucy i386 Packages  
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.laun


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/dists//ubuntu/saucy/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/dists//ubuntu/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/dists//ubuntu/saucy/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found


W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/dists//ubuntu/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found


E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I do not understand why am I getting this errors wine's ppa shows that 13.10 is available and the above I even do not know what is it ?? any help how to fix this

```
grep -rn "ubuntu-wine" /etc/apt/sources*

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa_-saucy.list:1:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa /ubuntu saucy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa_-saucy.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa /ubuntu saucy main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository isn't added properly to the APT sources. Have you been editing the `sources.list` file manually? Please don't do that!

As you can see APT now tries to fetch

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/dists//ubuntu/main/binary-i386/Packages
```

instead of (correct):

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages
```

Please use the `add-apt-repository` utility next time to add PPAs. I suggest to remove the repository from your `sources.list` for now and re-add the repository:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa_-saucy.list
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

again and it should use a working URL.

Comment: Funny have not touched them :D how did that happened  oo weight wine :D that is not my concern how ever this one http://ppa.launchpad.net /ubuntu/saucy i386 Packages I do not know why is it happening

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa_-saucy.list:1:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa /ubuntu saucy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa_-saucy.list:2:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa /ubuntu saucy main

Comment: Ok :) I have added them

Comment: @Levan I've updated my question with the additional instructions to remove the invalid entries. Now please remove the obsolete comments. :)